# Javascript browser console error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my javascript created in the directory :

> App / assets / javascript / product / products.js

In my Haml ***index.html.haml*** file, I've included this code to reference my js.file:

> = javascript_include_tag 'products'

and also in ***config / application.rb*** I've included :

> config.assets.precompile += ['products.js'].

However when my browser reloads, i get a red line error in the console showing

> GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/products.js 404 (Not Found) product:65.

Why is it getting from javascripts/products.js instead of going through the product directory file which i've put my script in there ?

In the script if I have the code alert, it gets triggered but if the codes are jquery, it won't run.

**Updated Answer :** 
in haml file **index.html.haml** use this :

> =javascript_include_tag(product/products.js)

Answer (score 0):

**/config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(  product/products.js )
```

**In you Haml index.html.haml file**

```
= javascript_include_tag :products
```

Try It

Comment: Hi Serhii it still doesn't work. The bootstrap nav active class doesn't respond and console still shows line :69 with :

""<script src="/javascripts/products.js"></script>""

Comment: Hi Serhii it works after changing in Haml file, to this :

=javascript_include_tag(product/products.js)